# Sets which are Hausdorff limits of Jordan curves

Tags: general-topology, curves

Are there known characterisations of sets which can be obtained as Hausdorff limits of Jordan curves in $S^2$?

Are there at least some limitations for such sets (other than being closed and connected)?

Comment: Do you have any idea what you are hoping for? What sort of properties do you suspect?

Comment: A first guess would be all path connected sets. Intuitively you cannot break this by taking a limit and there is a natural way to try and prove it via Zorn's lemma, but which doesn't quite go through. Perhaps worth mentioning is that you can break local connectedness by constructing the topologist's sine curve.